# Find convex $f$: $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \left| \frac{d^{n+1}}{ dx^{n+1}} e^{f} /\frac{d^{n}}{ dx^n} e^{f} \right|=\infty $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, convex-analysis

Does there exits a convex function $f$ that satisfies the following property: let 
\begin{align}
a_n= \left| \frac{ \frac{d^{n+1}}{ dx^{n+1}}  e^{f(x)}}{ \frac{d^{n}}{ dx^{n}} e^{f(x)}}   \right|_{x=1}
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n \to \infty}   \frac{a_n}{n} =\infty, 
\end{align}
but
\begin{align}
\liminf_{n \to \infty}   \frac{a_n}{n} <1. 
\end{align}

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for this edit.

Comment: Do you have anything strange about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Enough to show for $x=0$.

Consider $f = \ln(e^x + e^{x^2})$ .

Then $f'' =  \frac{e^{x^2}}{(e^x + e^{x^2})^2} \left(2e^{x^2} + (4x^2 - 4x +3)e^x \right) > 0 $. Thus $f$ is indeed a convex function.

I will represent $\frac{d}{dx}$ as $D$.

Indeed, $\boldsymbol{c_n \equiv D^n e^f \,\,|_{x=0}}  = D^n e^{x^2}\,\,|_{x=0} + D^n e^x\,\,|_{x=0} = 1 +D^n e^{x^2}\,\,|_{x=0}   $.

Now I will define sequence of polynomial as follows.

$$
\tilde{H}_n (x) = e^{-x^2} D^n e^{x^2} \quad(\Rightarrow D^n e^{x^2}\,\,|_{x=0} = \tilde{H}_n (0))
$$

It is similar to Hermit polynomial, but slightly different.

I will prove simple recurrence relation for $\tilde{H}_n (x)$, 
$$
\tilde{H}_{n+1} (x) = 2x\tilde{H}_{n} (x) + 2n\tilde{H}_{n-1} (x).
$$

---

Proof)
$$
{\tilde{H}_{n}}' (x) = D (e^{-x^2} D^n e^{x^2}) = -2xe^{-x^2} D^{n} e^{x^2} + e^{-x^2} D^{n+1} e^{x^2} \\ = -2x\tilde{H}_{n}(x) + \tilde{H}_{n+1}(x) \,-(1)
$$

Also,
$$
{\tilde{H}_{n}}' (x) = -2xe^{-x^2} D^{n} e^{x^2} + e^{-x^2} D^{n+1} e^{x^2} = -2xe^{-x^2} D^{n} e^{x^2} + e^{-x^2} D^{n}( 2xe^{x^2})\\ = -2xe^{-x^2} D^{n} e^{x^2} + e^{-x^2} (n \,D(2x)D^{n-1}e^{x^2} + 2x D^{n}e^{x^2} ) \\=2n\,e^{-x^2}D^{n-1}e^{x^2} = 2n{\tilde{H}_{n-1}} (x) \, - (2)
$$

By using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get our equality.

---

For convenience, I will define $b_n =  \tilde{H}_{n} (0)$.

Then $b_{n+1} =2nb_{n-1}$ (from above equality) and $b_0 = 1,\,\,b_1 = 0\,\,$ gives
$$
    b_n = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        0 & \text{for } n \text{ is odd}\\
        2^{n/2} (n-1)!! & \text{for } n \text{ is even}\\
        \end{array}\right\}.
$$

Now,
$$
    c_n = b_n\, + \,1 = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        1 & \text{for } n \text{ is odd}\\
        1+ 2^{n/2} (n-1)!! & \text{for } n \text{ is even}\\
        \end{array}\right\}
$$
and
$$
    a_n = \left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right|= \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        1+ 2^{(n+1)/2} (n)!! & \text{for } n \text{ is odd}\\
        {1}/({1+ 2^{n/2} (n-1)!!}) & \text{for } n \text{ is even}\\
        \end{array}\right\}.
$$

Finally we get
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty}   \frac{a_n}{n} =\infty \quad \&\quad  \liminf_{n \to \infty}   \frac{a_n}{n} =0 .
$$

($\because$ Since $[1+ 2^{(n+1)/2} (n)!! ]/ n \geq 2^{(n+1)/2} (n-1)(n-2)!!\,$.)

Comment: I referenced / https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+%28%282x-1%29+e%5E%28x%5E2%29%29%2F%28e%5Ex+%2B+e%5E%28x%5E2%29%29 / for $f''$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Give me some time to go over it. I might have some questions.

Comment: @Boby Sure. I will be waiting for it.

Comment: By the way, very cool construction.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment :)